# Vue Source Code Q1: confused about the "this._init"

Tags: vue.js

1. instance/index.js I wonder _init function not defined how can it be used

```
function Vue (options) {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' &&
    !(this instanceof Vue)
  ) {
    warn('Vue is a constructor and should be called with the `new` keyword')
  }
  this._init(options) // this line
}
initMixin(Vue)
```

2. instance/init.js _init defined here but I still don't understand

```
export function initMixin (Vue: Class<Component>) {
  Vue.prototype._init = function (options?: Object) {
  }
}
```

3. So I test by myself

```
function VueTest(str){
   this._init(str) // this equals to window right?
}

function initMixin(VueTest){
   Vue.prototype._init = function (str) {
      console.log(str)
   }
}

initMixin(new VueTest('vue'));

// console shows the error

VM63:2 Uncaught TypeError: this._init is not a function
    at new VueTest (<anonymous>:2:9)
    at <anonymous>:11:11
```

Maybe it looks stupid but I'm truly confused.

Answer (score 1):

if you invoke "this._init" in "function VueTest", you should define 
"VueTest.prototype._init = ... " in your "initMixin", not "Vue.prototype._init".